# If there is no post in a category, how to hide it

Tags: php, wordpress

If there is no post in category 19, how can I hide **Products** in html?

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul >
                <?php query_posts('showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=19'); ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><li><?php the_meta(meta_key); ?><?php the_title(); ?> </li></a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

example menu is here : http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/modern-jquery-accordion-menu

Comment: $(".has-sub span").hide();

Comment: But if it is not empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this from server side

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>

    <?php query_posts( 'showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=19'); if(have_posts()):?>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <li>
            <?php the_meta(meta_key); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </li>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endif;?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Using jQuery check and filter the empty product item by count of `li` elements and hide them

```
$('.has-sub').filter(function(){
    return $('ul li',this).length == 0;
}).hide()
```

Comment: Your jQuery alternative seems incorrect. It'll hide an `ul`.

Comment: @Mr.helmod : glad to help :)

Comment: @Pranav C Balan <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span</a>  "</span" is open if you close it.  someone can use it. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=19'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) { //       <------ check before entering while.
         while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><li><?php the_meta(meta_key); ?><?php the_title(); ?> </li></a>
<?php } endwhile; ?>
```